# Where is the Enum::valueOf defined?

Tags: kotlin, enums

When I define an enum class in Kotlin

```kotlin
enum class Answer {
    YES,
    NO
}
```

It has a `valueOf(value: String)` attached to it.

```kotlin
val doYouWantBeerOrCoffee = Answer.valueOf("YES") // Answer.YES
```

But where is this function actually defined? It is definitely not in the [Enum.Kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Enum.kt) and using Idea's `Go to Implementation` tool only takes me back to my `Answer` enum definition.

Answer (score 1):

It's generated by the compiler. That's what "synthetic" means in

> [Enum classes in Kotlin have synthetic methods allowing to list the defined enum constants and to get an enum constant by its name.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants)

If you decompile `Answer.class` you'll see it, but it isn't written as Kotlin (or Java) source code anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! I can see it in the byte code indeed. However, I still didn't manage to find the implementation. I mean where is the code that tells the compiler what it must generate? Is it in the compiler's code itself?

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Comment: Ok, but where? I'd like to see the code that does that. .)

Answer (score 0):

This method is a part of JDK, and defined in `Enum.java` class.
Which is the common base class of all Java language enumeration types.
Kotlin uses the same class for enums

Comment: `Enum` has a different `valueOf`, with 2 arguments as opposed to 1 in `Answer.valueOf("YES")`.